# How to get type of ERRORS in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I used yaml 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml
I want to catch the error and to check the insatnce

```
    import * as yaml from 'yaml';
    try{
        const yamlParse: any = yaml.parse(data);   
    } catch(err){
    if ( err instanceof YAMLError) 
...
    }
```

The problem that the compile doesn't know YAMLError
I tried also
yaml.YAMLError

I define in package.json

```
"@types/yaml": "1.0.2",
    "yaml": "^1.5.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably missing the import  `import { YAMLError } from '@types/yaml';` on top